# RFID does not respond after Ethernet.begin(mac, ip) initialization

Tags: ethernet, rfid

Good day, I have this problem with my simple project. I have a database with all RFID number of employee. What I want to do is to use an rfID to check if it is registered in the database. If it is, it would return a value of 1 else would be a value of 0.

I tried with arduino HanRun Ethernet shield. I was able to get a response from the php web server to the serial monitor. Tried the seeedrfid it successfully get the rfcard number. However, when i tried to combine the two, it would hang on Ethernet.begin(mac, ip) initialization. My code is below.

```
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <SeeedRFID.h>

#define RFID_RX_PIN 10
#define RFID_TX_PIN 11

SeeedRFID RFID(RFID_RX_PIN, RFID_TX_PIN);

char state = '0';
char c;
byte mac[] = {0x60, 0xF8, 0x1D, 0xBA, 0x1D, 0x52};
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 20, 228);

EthernetClient client;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Serial set up");

  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  Serial.print("My IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
}

void loop() {

  long rfID;
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

  if (RFID.isAvailable()) {
    rfID = RFID.cardNumber();
    Serial.println(rfID);
  }
}
```

Serial.println(rfID) is not executed unless I remove the Ethernet.begin(mac, ip). Can anybody point me to the right direction?

Comment: It's NOT a HanRun Ethernet Shield! It's an unbranded Ethernet Shield happens to use a HanRun HR911105A RJ45 Socket with Integrated Magnetics on it. http://www.kosmodrom.com.ua/pdf/HR911105A.pdf

Comment: What pins did you connect the RFIC board to?

Answer (score 1):

The Arduino Ethernet shield uses pins 4, 10,11,12,13. You have a conflict with the RFID pins.

Comment: SPI pins can overlap, SS should be independent. There's not too much info about the chipset used though.

Comment: can they overlap with software serial RX/TX?

Comment: SPI can't overlap with softserial.